# An issue when calling a Java class from R

Tags: java, r, classnotfoundexception, rjava

I have the following Java class:

```
public class Processor {
    public String showMsg(String msg) {
        return "The message is : " + msg;
    }

    public static void main(String [] arg) {
        Processor pro = new Processor();
        System.out.println(pro.showMsg(arg[0]));
    }
}
```

I would like to call this class from the following R script, which is my first time to use the `rJava` library:

```
testJav <- function(){
  library(rJava)
  .jinit()
  obj <- .jnew("/home/adam/eclipse-workspace/TestMeProject/bin/Processor.class")
  xx <- .jcall(obj,"Say hi to her") #I'm not sure if this is the right way to pass the message as a String argument!
  xx
}
```

When I run the script, I get the following error:

```
Error in .jnew("/home/adam/eclipse-workspace/TestMeProject/bin/Processor.class") : 
  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: /home/adam/eclipse-workspace/TestMeProject/bin/Processor/class
```

I thoutgh the problem is with `Processor.class` but even if I remove `.class`, I still get the same error.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

With your class (it's a good idea to have a package)

```
package mypackage;

public class Processor {
    public String showMsg(String msg) {
        return "The message is : " + msg;
    }

    public static void main(String [] arg) {
        Processor pro = new Processor();
        System.out.println(pro.showMsg(arg[0]));
    }
}
```

stored inside file `src/mypackage/Processor`

do following

```
> mkdir target
> javac -d target src/mypackage/Processor.java
> export CLASSPATH=`pwd`/target
> R
```

then, inside R, do foolowing

```
testJav <- function(){
  library(rJava)
  .jinit()
  obj <- .jnew("mypackage/Processor")
  xx  <- .jcall(obj, returnSig="Ljava/lang/String;", method="showMsg", "Say hi to her")
}
```

once you have everything in place, here's what you will get

```
> export CLASSPATH=`pwd`/target
> R
...
...
...
Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

> library(rJava)
> .jinit()
> obj <- .jnew("mypackage/Processor")
> xx  <- .jcall(obj, returnSig="Ljava/lang/String;", method="showMsg", "Say hi to her")
> xx
[1] "The message is : Say hi to her"
>
```

Have fun with `R` and `JNI` :)

**Fun fact**

Did you know that `javap` is super helpful when it comes to getting method's signature?

```
> javap -s mypackage/Processor
Compiled from "Processor.java"
public class mypackage.Processor {
  public mypackage.Processor();
    descriptor: ()V

  public java.lang.String showMsg(java.lang.String);
    descriptor: (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    descriptor: ([Ljava/lang/String;)V
}
```

Comment: Take a look here for samples related to macOS. At the bottom you have a full sample with Java code: http://www.owsiak.org/r-3-4-rjava-macos-and-even-more-mess/

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to pass a file path to `.jnew`, but `.jnew` doesn't take a file path. As stated in the [docs](https://www.rforge.net/doc/packages/rJava/html/jnew.html), the first argument is supposed to be a

> fully qualified class name in JNI notation (e.g. "java/lang/String").

Basically, if you would import your class in a Java program as `com.mystuff.MyClass`, then the name you should pass to `.jnew` would be `"com/mystuff/MyClass"`, regardless of where the `.class` file may be.

You may notice that this gives you no way to say where the file for the class is. That's because `.jnew` isn't where you tell rJava where to find things. [`.jpackage`](https://www.rforge.net/doc/packages/rJava/html/jpackage.html) would be the standard way for an R package to add its Java files to the Java classpath. If you want to add arbitrary directories or .jar files to the classpath, there's also a [`.jaddClassPath`](https://www.rforge.net/doc/packages/rJava/html/loader.html) function.